# String to HTML conversion so that page can read HTML tags

Tags: html, django, sqlite

I'm currently working on a blog using Django and SQLite for the back end. In my setup, I stored my articles in the database in this sort of form:

```
<p> <strong>The Time/Money Tradeoff</strong> </p> <p> As we flesh out High Life, Low Price, you will notice that sometimes we will suggest deals and solutions that may cost slightly more than their alternatives. We won’t always suggest the cheapest laptop...
```

On the page itself, I have this code for where I use the session data:

```
<p>{{request.session.article.0.blog_article}}</p>
```

I had assumed that the web broswer would be able to read the HTML tags. However, it prints on the page in that form, with the visible `<p>` tags and the like. I think this is because it's stored as a Unicode string in the database and is put onto the page between two quotation marks. If I paste the HTML code onto the page, the format looks like I wanted it to look, but I want it to be an automated process (tell Django which article ID I want, it plugs the elements of the page into the template and everything looks great).

How can I get the stored article in a form where the page can see the HTML tags?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default django would autoescape all strings in the template, so when you render html code in the template, they just show up as the literal html code. But you could use [`safe` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) to turn this off:

```
<p>{{request.session.article.0.blog_article|safe}}</p>
```

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much!